# Datetime field - MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

How can I insert the current date into a datetime field in MySQL database?

I have the code to connect to the database, make a query, and execute the query in php (which I've done plenty of times), but I've never dealt with dates in SQL or in PHP. Here's what I tried, but it's just returning 0 for the time:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("somewebsite.com","user","somepassword");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("someuser", $con);

$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );

$query = "insert into sometable
            (field1, field2, field3, date) 
          values 
            ('" . $_GET['name'] . "', '" . $_GET['pswd'] . "', '0', " . $phpdate . ")";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but passing $_GET parameters straight into your query leaves you wide open to SQL injection. You should sanitize all inputs. For info on SQL injection, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection There's also lots of questions on SO related to SQL injection prevention, so you can do a search on here for examples too.

Comment: Do a Google search for "Prepared Statements in PHP" (Here's a practical example from PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-920) , as that would be the best way. But at a very basic level, you can do mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']) instead of just $_GET['name']. You should also verify the inputs are as you expect. If you're expecting a numeric value, confirm the variable contains a numeric value, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = "insert into sometable (field1, field2, field3, date) 
           values ('" . $_GET['name'] . "', '" . $_GET['pswd'] . "', 
           '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the key, MySQL does it all for you.

Comment: sql injection attack waiting to happen

Comment: thanks that worked well. but, how do I make it so that it's eastern time zone?

Comment: @OMGPonies that is true, i was just referring to the timestamp bit.

Comment: There's also the `now()` function, which does the same thing.

Comment: @reising it will go with whatever timezone your server is set up for.

Comment: what's sql injection attack? is this a bad technique to use OMG Ponies?

Comment: @Neal - is there a way to force it to go to Eastern time?

Comment: @Marc B: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is ANSI, and widely supported

Comment: @MarcB That is true as well `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is one of the synonyms for `now()`

Comment: @reising, you have to verify your gets or people can `bobby table` your database

Comment: @reising -- you can force it by setting the server time

Comment: @OMGPonies lol we had the same story, but i did not provide the link ^_^

Comment: @neal - how do I verify the gets?

Comment: @Neal, @Marc B, @OMGPonies - does anyone know how I can force the database to do eastern time without changing my server?

Comment: @reising: `set time_zone=yourtimezonehere` in a query.

Answer (score 0):

$date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", time() );

or, for $phptime

$date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $phptime ) );

Comment: What happens if the PHP executes at 11:59:59pm and the query doesn't take place until 00:00:01am the next day? Best to let MySQL do the timestamping to keep things consistent.

Comment: What if he is doing it from a value he previously had stored? He will be inserting the value he performed the operation on.

Comment: If he wants to use the current time, he could just use NOW().

Comment: Also, be sure to make use of mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent SQL injection.